# How to save hibernate search indexed files into project WEB-INF folder?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

How can I save hibernate search using JPA indexed files into project WEB-INF folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ServletContext.getRealPath` to get the physical path of the `/WEB-INF` folder. Be aware that depending on your deployment method, the WEB-INF folder may be cleared on redeployment. It would probably be a better idea to save the data somewhere else.